# Trying to use jQuery to trigger an anchor click after the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this has been asked a number of times on here, and while I've read all of the threads I can find, this still isn't working for me.

A little background: I'm working on a Wordpress site with a grid plugin, and I'm trying to trigger a filter when the page loads, depending on a url parameter. For the purpose of this thread I've just hardcoded a url parameter (the category variable) as an example because that functionality is working fine.

The anchor tag I'm trying to trigger:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="ladda-button" data-category="55" data-style="zoom-in">Tarps and Covers</a>
```

The broken code I'm trying to use to trigger the click event:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        var category = '55';
        var anchor = $("[data-category=" + category + "]");
        anchor.click();
    });
</script>
```

A console log returning the anchor variable confirms that I'm selecting the correct jQuery object, and I've also tried `anchor[0].click()` to trigger it with no success. Does anyone see any problems that I'm overlooking?

Comment: You have `href="javascript:;"`. So clicking it won't have any effect (unless it has click event listeners that will be called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        var category = '55';
        var anchor = $("[data-category=" + category + "]");
        anchor.click();
      anchor.on('click',()=>{
             alert();
       })
    });
```

Everything is working

Comment: Thank you for the anchor.on('click'... suggestion, I tried that and got it to work too so it looks like the problem lies somewhere else. Thanks for your help.